# my ng-include does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to use ng-include but it does not show the html files which I refered.

app.js code

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('mainCtrl', [$scope, function($scope)
    {
      $scope.templateID = 'testing1.html';

      $scope.changeTemplateID = function($scope){
          $scope.templateID = 'testing2.html';
        }

    }]);
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ng-include src="templateID"></ng-include>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <p ng-click="changeTemplateID()">next</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

There are two html file in the root directory. They are called *testing1.html* and *testing2.html*. I even tried to refer them directly like *"'testing1.html'"* in the ng-include.

but no success. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors in your JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //                          vvvvvvvv  must be a string
    app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
    {
      $scope.templateID = 'testing1.html';

      // you don't need to pass $scope here:
      $scope.changeTemplateID = function(){
          $scope.templateID = 'testing2.html';
        }

    }]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GO01HpGyha38bLwUI7LJ) for your perusal.

Comment: I updated the code. You have $scope as a parameter in changeTemplateID. Don't need it ... $scope is already in, er, scope. Check the plunkr if you are lost.

Comment: you still have $scope as a parameter ... it MUST be `$scope.changeTemplateID = function(){` < no $scope as paramter

Answer (score 0):

`app.controller('mainCtrl', [$scope, function($scope)...`
Your `[$scope` must be `['$scope'` like a string, change it and you'll be fine )

Comment: Changed it.  
 
No success still :(

Comment: Should work, do you get any errors in the browser console?